# Why is my for loop not taking 9 inputs?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

My code only takes 5 values as input.? What am i doing wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char arr[3][3];
    int i,j,n;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            scanf("%c",&arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How should i correct it?

Comment: input sample would be nice, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change

```
scanf("%c",&arr[i][j]);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c",&arr[i][j]);.
```

Notice the space given before specifier to consume `\n` left in stdin buffer when you pressed enter.

Each `\n` is working as input taking your space from input space.

Comment: It worked. But why doesn't this problem occurs in case of "%d".?

Comment: @user2556926 Most format specifiers including %d skip whitespace, but %c doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

It should work, but note that `%c` will read only a single character. Whitespace is not suppressed as it is for other (more "high-level") format specifiers, so if you're separating your characters by blanks of any kind those will be read instead of the actual characters.

Also note that you should check the return value of `scanf()`, it can fail if no suitable input is present.

Answer (score 1):

The first input is stored in arr[0][0] then when you press enter(return key) it is stored in arr[0][1] and while you think you are inputting the second character actually you are giving the third input. Try the code below to see if you didnt get it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char arr[3][3];
    int i,j,n;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
        printf("Input array [%d][%d]",i,j);
            scanf("%c",&arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

And as for the correction you need a `scanf(" %c",&arr[i][j]);` a space infront of %c to consume the `\n`

Hope it answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can use `gets(arr[i][j])`

instead of `scanf("%c",&arr[i][j]);`

This will work perfectly. It is good idea to use `gets() and  puts()` function instead of `printf()` and `scanf()` function for string and character in C

Comment: No. First, `gets` need a parameter of type `char *`. Second, `gets` is dangerous, one should always avoid it and use `fgets` or `gets_s` instead. Third, `printf` is for formatted output, `puts` is hardly a replacement in many situations.

Comment: o actually it is `getc` instead of `gets` and it always works fine for the above program and related.

Answer (score -2):

you can use fflush(stdin)

```
char arr[3][3];
int i,j,n;
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        scanf("%c",&arr[i][j]);
        fflush(stdin);
    }
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior. It may work on a particular implementation but is not portable.

Comment: This is undefined behavior, since fflush is meant to be called on an output stream. have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin).